# In perl,how can I know how long a specific file has been existing?

Tags: perl

I've checked the doc but seems there's no such a column in the output of `stat`:

```
             8 atime    last access time in seconds since the epoch
             9 mtime    last modify time in seconds since the epoch
            10 ctime    inode change time in seconds since the epoch (*)
```

Is it possible to know how long a specific file has been existing at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no way to obtain that information, because the file system on a POSIX system does not have a creation time field.

If your filesystem has extended attributes (xattr), it may store the file creation time. But then you would have to grab that using the xattr interface, not via `stat`.

And alas, Googling for "perl xattr" doesn't yield anything useful.

Comment: seems there's no such function as `xattr`.

Comment: @new_perl: It's not a function. You would have to grab an `xattr` Perl module from CPAN. Sadly, that module does not appear to exist.

Comment: Try searching for "extattr": use either [File::ExtAttr](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ExtAttr) or [File::ExtAttr::Tie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ExtAttr::Tie), depending on which interface style you prefer.  Of course, this won't help if the filesystem you use doesn't store creation time in an extended attribute.

Comment: On the other hand, if you also control file creation you can simply keep a log of creation times.  If the log is likely to grow large, you could store it in a DB like SQLite, with a primary key being the full path.